# playing sound files in resources folder

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have some mp3 files in my resources folder, how can i play those mp3 files? I just know their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to supplement [@Georg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172521/playing-sound-files-in-resources-folder/3172538#3172538)'s answer.

As you can see from the doc, `-URLForResource:withExtension:` is available only since 4.0. As 3.x is still widespread, it's better to use the backward-compatible methods:

- By converting a path to NSURL:

  ```
  NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"mp3"];
  NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
  ....
  ```
- or, by CoreFoundation methods:

  ```
  CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMain(),
                                         CFSTR("myFile"), CFSTR("mp3"), NULL);
  ....
  CFRelease(url);
  ```

Comment: Oops, thats what i get for quickly throwing it together :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). To get the URL for the files use `NSBundle`s [`-URLForResource:withExtension:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-SW9) (or downward compatible alternatives, see Kennys answer):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myFile" withExtension:@"mp3"];
NSError *error = 0;
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
// check error ...
[player play];
// ...
```

And don't forget to read the Multimedia Programming Guides section on [using audio](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6).